# How to represent subcategories of a category in an ERD

Tags: sql, database, entity-relationship, erd

I have a requirement document for a database that I am currently working on. However I am stuck and I need some assistance. It reads,

> Every book belongs to one book category which has a category ID and a
> name. The library has it books divided into categories and
> subcategories. Every subcategories belong to only one category

Here is my attempt. Make corrections where you feel necessary or suggest a better diagram.

[image: ERD image for book category]

Comment: I do not recognize this diagram notation, what is the small circle with a 'd' in it?

Comment: @Kurt.. the 'd' represents a generalization hierarchy. I am representing subcategory as a subclass.

Comment: @NickW.. i had a whole document to translate into an ERD. And the part that I had challenge was what I quoted above. Basically where to place the subcategory in the diagram is the headache. I do not need you to mark my homework. The more reason I showed the attempt I have made so that you can critique it. Cos it does feel like I am missing an important detail in the diagram.

Comment: A few questions.  Is this model for a single library?  If so then books should belong to subcategories rather than directly to categories.  If for multiple libraries and they can assign the same book to different subcategory depending on which library it is in, then you'll need some additional entities.

Comment: @Kurt, that helps. Yes... It's for a single library and that was exactly what I needed. If the books belong to the subcategories, how do I represent the "every subcategories belong to one category". Create another entity for category and indicate a mandatory 1 to 1 relationship between category and subcategory? Or...

Comment: simplest way is to just have distinct Category and Subcategory entities.  Remove the subclass and just make it 1:M relation.  If you want to keep the subclassing, I would make Category and Subcategory both subclasses of a more general type such as Classification.  Then you can also have the 1:M relation between them as distinct subclasses of the same superclass.

Comment: @Kurt, Thank you. This helps quite a lot. Already sketched out the bit and makes a lot more sense. Is your initial suggestion still relevant to this distinct category solution you posited? I mean, would you still suggest I connect the books directly to subcategories instead of categories. The requirement document does state that every book belongs to one book category (not subcategories).

Comment: yes, books belong to subcategories which belong to categories, so by transitive property books belong to a single category automatically.

Comment: Thank you @Kurt. Much appreciate your time.